# Движение шара по параболе

Tags: java

Думаю, многие из вас начинали свой путь с AnyLogic с методическим пособием товарища Мезенцева.
И вот, во втором разделе есть задание - создать модель движения шара по параболе.
Я пытался прописать в ивенте вот так:

```
for (double i= -10; i <= 10 ;i = i + 0.1){
x = time()*Math.pow(i, 2);
}
```

и вот так:

```
for (double i= -10; i <= 10 ;i = i + 0.1){
 double A = 1; 
 double B = 0; 
 double C = 0;
 x = (A*i*time()*time()+i*B*time()*+C);
}
```

и даже были попытки реализации, как бы, тела брошенного под углом 45 градусов.
Подскажите, в чем я не прав?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, почему вы решили, что в чем-то не правы - какой результат у вас ожидается? Какой получается?

Comment: time() это что?

Comment: второй вариант сводится к ``x = (i*time()*time());``

Comment: Эникейщик, time() это время МОДЕЛЬНОЕ, прошедшее с начала моделирования. Поздно понял.

Comment: ну у вас обе формулы неправильные

Comment: @Эникейщик, я понял....

Comment: Наткнулся на похожее на форуме https://www.cyberforum.ru/anylogic/thread1835462.html но не до конца понял что куда...

Answer (score 0):

При движении в поле тяжести тела, брошенного со скоростью V0 под углом Alpha, координаты меняются от времени так, как в восьмом классе проходили:

```
X = X0 + V0*Cos(Alpha)*t
Y = Y0 + V0*Sin(Alpha)*t - g*t*t/2
```

X0, Y0 - Начальные координаты

t - ваше время с начала движения

g - ускорение свободного падения

Comment: Неособо понял..

Comment: Что именно непонятно? Дописал, что значат буковки.

Comment: Так и написать в проекте?

Comment: Да, задаете константы, по мере работы (цикл или таймер) у вас меняется переменная t, вычисляете X и Y. На всякий случай переписал "t в квадрате" как t*t